# Pulling Out Values from JSON Association

Tags: parsing, json-format, xml

Having a bit of trouble pulling a value out of a JSON Association here. I am scraping this website: http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/history/fi-126.1.BY.NYS

I want to scrape the closing stock prices for everyday, and using developer tools found the JSON link that stores the data, with the link: http://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartDataV5?symbols=\
126.1.BY.NYS&chartType=1y&isEOD=False&lang=en-US&isCS=true&isVol=true

I've gotten rather close, and have narrowed down the association and keys using this:

```
res1 = Association[
   Import["http://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/\
ChartDataV5?symbols=126.1.BY.NYS&chartType=1y&isEOD=False&lang=en-US&\
isCS=true&isVol=true", "JSON"]];
Keys[res1];
data = res1["Series"];
Keys[data];
content = "p" /. data
```

This block of code essentially returns that the values I am seeking are under the "p" Key, for instance:

```
{"T" -> 9201600, "P" -> 20.05, "Hp" -> 20.48, "Lp" -> 19.84, 
 "Op" -> 20.35, "V" -> 3492724}
```

I want to extract the 20.05 in "p" -> 20.05.
There are several "p" values in data, and ideally I would grab all of them and put them into a list.

Comment: Replace `p` with `P`? `content = "P" /. data`

Comment: Sometimes I am surprised by my own lack of attention to detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I think you can make your life a bit easier by using RawJSON as input format specification. It basically makes Mathematica use Associations where appropriate when importing JSON.

```
url = "http://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartDataV5?symbols=126.1.BY.NYS&chartType=1y&isEOD=False&lang=en-US&isCS=true&isVol=true";
import = Import[url, "RawJSON"]
```

Try the request with both RawJSON and JSON for yourself. Since our data now consists of lists and associations, we can conveniently process it using `Part`. This should accomplish what you were asking for:

```
Part[import, 1, "Series", All, "P"]
{20.05, 20.1, 20.2, 20.18, 20.27, 20.35, 20.3}
```

Comment: That definitely makes things easier. Thank you!